# Can I ping all AWS buckets in the world?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, ping, ip-blocking

I have 2 questions,

1. Can I ping all the AWS buckets in the world? I would use a simple shell script which will curl with a dictionary of names/number combinations or some other method.
2. Will my IP be blocked if I do this? If so, why? This is not a DOS attack, is it?

I searched in Google and Stack Overflow, but couldn’t find any related question or answer.

Comment: Why would you want to do it?

Comment: I dont understand why a downvote but there are several reasons, one reason can be to create an API to identify and report less secure servers.

Comment: I didn't downvote.

Comment: You can try, but I strongly suspect AWS will block you if you do it at a high rate or with many threads in parallel. You'll probably need to brute force bucket names, so it will take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, You can't ping all, because AWS already have IP/GEO/Other logic based access history and records based logic, they will block your id and inform bucket admins.

Comment: thanks for the information, what if i ping for a certain subnet (a random set) and look for the hostname & if it has s3.amazonaws.com then i will visit the bucket and check if it is accessebile or not. Will i still be blocked if i do only positive requests ?

Comment: You cannot "ping a bucket" because bucket names are merely logical containers served by Amazon S3. There is no direct relationship between IP addresses and buckets. Resolving the DNS name of an S3 bucket would only return the address of an Amazon S3 server.